# Redirecting index.html to [SITE PATH]/phpmyadmin/

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to redirect users from the index.html page to a phpmyadmin login at https://www.mysite.load.balancer.com

However because I have a production and testing server, with different paths but which I want to behave the same, I'd like the "root" server path to be used and appended with /phpmyadmin/ during the redirect. How can I do this? Currently my code looks like this, in the head section of my index.html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='https://mysite.load.balancer.com/phpmyadmin/'" />
```

So I would want something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='$SITE_DOM/phpmyadmin/'" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Method #1

You could use superglobal variables like $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; to get your domain. Than you can redirect with

```
<?php header('Location: $_SEVER['SERVER_NAME']/phpmyadmin/'); ?>
```

Method #2

Use the same superglobal variable in your meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='<?php echo $_SEVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/phpmyadmin/'" />
```